# How to maintain border-radius property of image when using transform:scale() on hover?

Tags: css, hover, transform, zooming

I want to zoom image on mouse hover in my web page. Image is in a table cell. I applied transform:scale(1.2). It works properly. But problem is that image has border-radius : 10px and when mouse pointer goes on the image, then image border-radius becomes zero. and after full transition it becomes 10px again.
I want to keep it unchanged at the time of zooming. It is not working only in google chrome.
CSS of this effect are as following...

```
.ProductImageStyle {
 border-radius:10px;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition:all .5s;
 transition:all .5s;}

.ProductImageStyle:hover {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
 transform:scale(1.2); }

.ProductTableCell {
overflow:hidden;
text-align:justify;
border-radius:10px; }
```

And asp.net code is below...

```
<asp:Table ID="tblProducts" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="20">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="ProductTableCell">                    
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="./Images/1.jpg" runat="server" Height="200" Width="100%" CssClass="ProductImageStyle"/>                    
            </asp:TableCell>               
        </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Please provide appropriate solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried applying the border-radius to an element wrapping the image, instead of the image itself?

Comment: Been a while since I've seen WebForms .NET ... Do you have the rendered HTML output?

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry I did not get anything yet. :(